# Testing if a proof is sound in Idris

Tags: testing, idris, theorem-proving

I'm trying to write a test code to check if `plusComm : (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> a + b = b + a` indeed proves `a + b = b + a` on natural numbers, i.e. the code does not fake one using typed holes, `postulate`, `believe_me`, `assert_total`, etc.

Specifically, if the proof is faked in some way, I want the program to fail in one of the three ways:

- Compilation error
- Run-time error e.g. segfault
- Run-time infinite loop

If these options are not feasible, I'm open to source code analysis as a last resort (for my purposes, that should be written in Idris too). I heard of `Language.Reflection` but I'm not sure if it's the right tool here.

The code below is one attempt that failed because `proofEval` doesn't even look at the actual value passed:

```
plusComm : (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> a + b = b + a
plusComm a b = ?plusComm

proofEval : {a : ty} -> (a = b) -> ty
proofEval {a=a} _ = a

main : IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Compiled Successfully!"
  print (proofEval (plusComm 1 2))
```

The above, when compiled and run, produces the following output and exits without error.

```
Compiled Successfully!
3
```

Answer (score 1):

### Partial answer

I found [a way to catch `postulate` and holes using dependent tuples](https://tio.run/##rVJNS8NAEL3nVzyLYLYlh1ZPgShaPAiiYqUHL2XbbOzCJhv2o1LE3x4nCWljDyJWlh1m9715b2dYmRppqyqK8BFhzpVMURqts6BU3k51niNGyCk8cMcQXSJc9g4cIyyR0B6B70sSdKl33MmNCEg/@gwC8phyKzCO8bItRYq1VuJIq6suPzSZxHjS1nnFHXl0Gf7gdiB8HuNGKCk2ArlAWGiHFfdva8eOaoW3l63yolZuiOzQ/iLGtbXCODjtuPrvB/BGe9Fqn@7GddbA72thRACU3DhJ@B79vR96Va@0EjyLTHVdNr/vdkPaPyl2CIbDHdDk36wYYz29tj1itDUU@50TNci5LEjr7hEhaw8JUl0/2LuZM/cFBkQvpaKfO/OrlbA280ptTwY1x8jC0cAyW0dbpPXwduZjTKrqCw):

```
plusComm : (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> a + b = b + a
plusComm = plusCommutative

proofEval : (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> (a : Nat ** (b : Nat ** (a + b = b + a)))
proofEval a b = (a ** (b ** plusComm a b))

main : IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Compiled Successfully!"
  print $ fst $ snd $ proofEval 1 2
  -- `print $ fst $ proofEval 1 2` doesn't work for the purpose
```

Output:

```
Compiled Successfully!
2
```

Some possible fake proofs and the results:

```
-- typed hole
plusComm : (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> a + b = b + a
plusComm = ?plusComm
-- result: runtime error (abort)
ABORT: Attempt to evaluate hole Main.plusComm1

-- postulate
postulate plusComm : (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> a + b = b + a
-- result: compilation error
reachable postulates:
  Main.plusComm
```

Note that **`assert_total` or `believe_me` is not caught using this method** as marked in the linked snippet.